# MySQL difficulties -  Hiragana and Katakana are treated as the same

Tags: mysql, unicode

I tried to fetch ピース on mysql database
SELECT * FROM edict WHERE japanese = 'ピース'
However I got 3 results which are:
ヒース
ビーズ
ピース

I tried to use ぴーす as the query and it also return the same result.
SELECT * FROM edict WHERE japanese = 'ぴーす'

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure about japanese alphabets, but you could use [BINARY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-binary-op.html) comparison:

```
WHERE BINARY japanese = 'ピース'
```

`BINARY` keyword casts string to its binary presentation, thus you have "precise" comparison.

Also, if that behaviour should be default for `japanese` column - you could change its collation to `_bin` one (it will be more efficient solution, rather than just casting)

Comment: Both ピース and ぴーす are syllabic (biisu). Sometimes Japanese uses Katakana for names or emphasis - so they're often the same word and meaning. I'd actually have thought it's a very useful feature of MySQL (when you're aware of it) - but it's also useful to search for the exact character. +1 :)