# Why does MySQL treat Japanese alphabets hiragana and katakana the same, and how can you make it compatible with Django?

Tags: mysql, django

This question was partially addressed here, but I wanted to ask more specifically:

[MySQL difficulties -  Hiragana and Katakana are treated as the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050221/mysql-difficulties-hiragana-and-katakana-are-treated-as-the-same)

Japanese has 2 separate phonetic alphabets describing the same set of sounds, and MySQL appears to treat these two alphabets the same way they treat upper and lower case (so I suppose, rather than case insensitive, it's alphabet insensitive). However, these two alphabets are not analogous to English case, so it doesn't make much sense to do that. Does anybody know why they chose to do it this way, and an easy work around? More specifically, when connected to django, you get this problem:

```
>>> ichi = 'イチ' # This word is in katakana
>>> Dictionary.objects.get(word=ichi).word # The record that is returned is in hiragana
'いち' 
>>> Dictionary.objects.get(word=ichi).word == ichi # The words are not the same
False
```

Does anyone know how I can make the behavior consistent?

Comment: Is it an option to have two databases for hiragana/katagana? Is changing database type an option?

Comment: As for why they chose to do it this way, [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050221/mysql-difficulties-hiragana-and-katakana-are-treated-as-the-same#comment8752577_7050237) on the linked question seems to suggest it was intended as feature since these words are often the same word and meaning?  "Sometimes Japanese uses Katakana for names or emphasis - so they're often the same word and meaning."

Comment: I saw that--while that is true, I would say that the usage of kata/hiragana is deliberate and meaningful the majority of the time (katakana is designated for foreign words, and hiragana for native Japanese words)

Comment: Are you really using a mysql database as opposed to default sqlite database used by Django? I am using MySQL, and I do not have this problem, i.e., in my queries I am able to get results that differentiate イチ and いち. If you are sure that you are using MySQL, please share your database-related settings (omitting sensitive info of course).

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because MySQL treats hiragana and katakana as the same when the column field is set to utf_general_ci.

change the column collation to utf_bin